# Creating Custom Class for loading Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

Every time I load a grid view, I need a `Datasource` and I have to bind the data with the source `DataBind()`. I want to skip this so I made a function. Which is working. But when I create the class, `Gridview`, I get a `System.Web.UI.WebControls` not found Exception. Can you explain the problem to me and a potential fix?

I have added the `System.web` namespace.

```
protected void LoadToGv(GridView GV, string qry)
{
    DataTable dt = DC.GetDataTable(qry);
    if (dt != null)
    {
        GV.DataSource = dt;
        GV.DataBind();
    }
}
```

And while making it a public method of a class library it's giving the error `Reference Not found`. Is there any other way to accomplish it.

Comment: Did you add a reference to System.web to the project with the class?

Comment: Yes,I added reference of System.web to that custom class. @TonyAbrams

Comment: Where is class code?

Comment: Are you getting an *exception* (when you run it) or an error (when you compile it)? Please cut and paste the message instead of paraphrasing.

Comment: In order for us to help you better, please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @JohnWu  It was a Compile time error. But It solved automatically. May be for some reason it could not find the reference on that time. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to use `System.Web.Extensions` as reference. And That's solve the problem